# Render SSRS Reports in .docx instead of .doc

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server R2 reporting service for designing reports and integrated then in ASP.Net using Report Viewer 11. When user exports the report in Word format, the extenction of report is .doc which makes the size of the report very high. Is there any was we can change the format to .docx so that the size of the file is reduced.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved using Word Renderer.

> In SQL Server Reporting Services, the default Word renderer is the
>   version that renders to the Microsoft Word format (.docx). This is the
>   Word option that the Export menus in a Reporting Services web portal
>   and SharePoint list.
>
> WORDOPENXML - Soft page-break - Displayed as "Word" in the export menu
>   when viewing reports. The Word rendering extension renders a report as
>   a Word document (.docx) that is compatible with Microsoft Word 2013.
>   For more information, see Exporting to Microsoft Word.

```
<Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering" Visible="false"/>

<Extension Name="WORDOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-word-report-builder-and-ssrs) link.

Comment: This works in direct links to the report as well - when using &rs:Format=WORDOPENXML as part of the url to the report